# FFMPEG 3 video Concat / Overlay

Tags: ffmpeg, concatenation, overlay

I have been getting to grips with FFMPEG for the last few days...so please excuse my lack of knowledge. It's very much early days.

**I need to join 3 video elements together with one of the videos becoming an overlay at a specific time.**

intro.mp4

mainvideo.mp4

endboard.mp4

I need the **intro.mp4** to bolt on to the front of the **mainvideo.mp4** and then with 20 seconds to go before the end of the **mainvideo.mp4**, I need the **endboard.mp4** video to be bolted on to the sequence and take over the frame. When this happens, I then need the **mainvideo.mp4** to be overlayed in the top left corner and continue playing seamlessly through the transition.

I also need the audio from the main video to play until the end of the video.

There will be lots of **mainvideo.mp4** files that this will be applied to individually, and the lengths of these videos will always be different. I am hoping that there is a way to have the transition to the **endboard.mp4** happen relative to 20secs before the end of the files.

I roughly understand in theory what needs to be done, but being so new to this world I am really unsure of how something this complicated would be pieced together.

If there is anyone out there that can help me , it would be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

virtually split main video, 20 sec before the end. if video 60 sec, split in 40 sec. added 5th input for audio

```
ffmpeg \
-i "intro.mkv" \
-to 40 -i "main_60sec.mkv" \
-ss 40 -i "main_60sec.mkv" \
-i "endboard.mkv" \
-i "main_60sec.mkv" \
-filter_complex "
[0:v][1:v]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[1v];
[2:v]scale=iw/2:-2[2v];
[3:v][2v]overlay[3v];
[1v][3v]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0;
[0:a][4:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1
" output.mp4 -y
```

or using trim:

```
ffmpeg \
-i "intro.mp4" \
-i "main_60sec.mp4" \
-i "end.mp4" \
-filter_complex "
[1:v]trim=duration=40,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[m1];
[1:v]trim=start=40,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[m2];
[0:v][m1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[v1];
[m2]scale=iw/2:-2[m2];
[2:v][m2]overlay[v2];
[v1][v2]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0;
[0:a][1:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1
" output.mp4 -y
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping with this, greatly appreciated! I have a few questions, if you don't mind.

1. Is it possible to have the audio from the main video play? So the audio plays when the video is full screen and continues to play when it transitions to be the overlay video?

2. Is there any way to achieve this where the whole file does not need to be re-encoded? Is it possible to just re-encode the section that has the overlay? I am concerned that when the main video file is long (1-2 hours long) this process may take too much time to achieve. 

Thank you again!

Comment: To confirm, I need the video and audio to play from the intro video, then the video and audio to play from the main video, and still have the audio play when the video transitions to the overlay mode. Thank you